# static files not loading only on django admin page

Tags: django, production-environment

This is on a production server with DEBUG = False. My static files will load on the home page but not the admin page. It gives me a error 404 in the browser console. This only happens on the admin page. I've checked to make sure that the .css files are in the specified directory's and they are along with the code inside them. NOTE: The same server and file structure was working earlier. I've tried almost everything I can think of any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Did you `collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried rebooting and restarting nginx and gunicorn. I've checked where the static files are served from in nginx and the settings.py there're all correct. The reason why I think they're all correct is because all of my other pages load the car fine. Only the admin page doesn't.

Comment: Could we see your project's `settings.py`? Particularly the settings related to static content.

Comment: I added the code regarding the settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I set the `/static` in nginx config for django but not the path for `/static/admin`. Thank you everyone for you help. Happy coding.